# P-Ch high side switch output drop?

Tags: power, mosfet, switches, power-electronics, output

I am making a cutoff switch for a SLA battery using the this circuit

[image]

V2 is the SLA battery, V5 is 0V or 5V coming from a some other logic circuitry. The simulation comes out fine. I understand that the parameters for the FET's are different (between simulation and my FET), but Rds(on) is low enough that it shouldn't effect it. I am using this P-Ch FET [AOD403](http://www.aosmd.com/pdfs/datasheet/AOI403.pdf).

**When I put a large load (5A) on the output, I see an output drop(droop) of ~1.0V, so ~11V across the load. Why is that happening, and how do I fix it?**

@5A VGS = -11.5V

@5A VDS = 23mV

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you see a fairly small \$V_{DS}\$ at 5A.  The switch seems to be performing nominally.  Is it possible that the internal resistance of the battery is causing the droop?

Comment: How can you say "The simulation comes out fine." with an n-type MOSFET?

Comment: Are you using the TO252 or the TO251A, and how are you connecting your source? And are you measuring 1 volt from source to drain, or are you measuring 11 volts at the drain and assuming the source is still at 12 volts? If you are actually dropping 1 volt you are dissipating 5 watts, and that will kill a non-heatsunk MOSFET - so how long did you run it while you took measurements?

Comment: You're right WhatRoughBeast. That was a screw up trying to quickly simulate the design and swap out parts before my free 10min demo was up. I am using the p-channel called out in the datasheet. I am using the TO251A modified to fit into perf board. I have 2 multimeters; 1 at the input, and the other across the load. So I could see 12.2V on the input (source) and 11.3V at the drain.

Comment: @J.Drulia - and how long did you run it and why didn't the MOSFET die? Did it at least smell hot? And what is your load resistor for real?

Comment: Are you sure that you connected the MOSFET the right way? Connect a MOSFET the wrong way (D and S swapped over) and it will still conduct, but through the internal body diode. You can expect a drop of around 0.7 to 0.8V at 5A. A quick test is does it switch the current on/off using V5?

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast - I have two 6Ω/50W and a 12Ω/50W paralleled together to give me a ~5A load. It doesn't really smell hot. I put a FLIR camera on it and its about 118°F(case) which is under the Tj limit. Since I'm connected to a battery, I only leave the load on for a few minutes at a time.

Comment: @NickAlexeev - this is why I'm kinda confused. The mosfet appears to be working, but there's such a large drop on the output. I'm charging the battery overnight, so we'll see if that makes a difference in the morning.

Comment: @SteveG toggling V5 turns the FET on/off as intended.

Comment: Why does the CircuitLab schematic have a load of 700mΩ? Ignoring R\$_{DS}\$, that would produce a 17A load.

Comment: @J.Drulia - Try measuring the voltage drop across the MOSFET directly, rather than using two different meters and subtracting the difference. Also, use your camera or your finger to verify that all 3 resistors are indeed getting hot. The two 6 ohm jobbers, in particular, should be the same temperature.

Comment: If Tcase is 118C your MOSFET is very close to too hot. Tjunction = 118 + Pdis * Thetajc. If you use 5A * 0.9V, that is 4.5W. Thetajc is 1 typical, and 1.5 max. If you use the typical, you are at around 122C. If you use the max, you are right at the max junction temp. The basic design should be fine. Just make sure the pullup goes from source to gate, and connect the source to the battery, gate to the load and it should work fine. If you do that, the FET should be hard on, and remain very close to ambient.

Comment: I figured out the issue. After moving the FETs to a bare copper pcb for proper heatsinking, the problem persisted. @5A Vds = 16mV and Vgs = -11.03V so the FET was behaving as it should. **I found that the issue was the voltage was dropping in my mini-grabber jumper wires.** That is probably obvious to some, but it wasn't to me. I was just mocking up the design and didn't think about the wires being able to handle higher loads...doh. Thanks for everyone's help and at least validating that it wasn't a bad design, just bad prototyping mock-up...